# CSS keyframe animation not working on div element using opacity

Tags: css

I have div .list element with CSS below

```
.list{
    bottom:0;
    height:calc(100% - 85px);
    left:50%;
    max-width:600px;
    padding-bottom:85px;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-5%);
    z-index:-1;
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    position:fixed;
    justify-content:center;
    opacity:0;
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
```

I use JavaScript to add .anim class to this element which contains animation to open .list div element on click open button

```
document.querySelector('.list').classList.add('anim');
```

.anim class should animate opening .list using CSS animation.

```
.anim {
    -webkit-animation:openlist 200ms ease forwards;
    z-index:2
}

@-webkit-keyframes openlist {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-5%)
    }
    
    to {
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,0);
    opacity:1
    }
}
```

**Problem with opacity:** when I use Opacity outside CSS animation and put it inside .anim class after animation definition like below:

```
.anim {
    -webkit-animation:openlist 200ms ease forwards;
    z-index:2;
    opacity:1;
}
```

.list div is scrollable without any problem but I don't get transition effect from opacity:0 to 1.

If I use opacity inside animation like below:

```
to {
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,0);
    opacity:1
}
```

Everything is working fine but .list div is not scrolling and scrollbar is hidden.

**HTML**

```
<body class="x">

  <input type="search" class="s2" placeholder="Search...">
  <div class="s1"></div>

  <div class="c1"></div>
  <div class="list"></div>
  <img src="icons/heart.svg" id="m">

</body>
```

**BODY CSS:**

```
.x {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:90px 0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

**Question:** How to get CSS animation working with opacity inside and keep transition effect plus .list div scrollable?

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas Thanks for your reply but i tried this way and still not working. Putting opacity:0 inside 0% {} gives same effect

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas Problem is that animation with opacity inside makes div not scrollable and without opacity inside but outside after animation definition in .anim class div is scrolling fine but transition is not working. I added html to question

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas Yes they are containers for some javascript generated text

Comment: sorry, I can't figure it out. I am sorry. I hope you find someone with more experience with this stuff. I will delete my answer so people can find this question easily as not answered. have a good day!

Comment: can you share the jsfiddle , so i can have a look

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kc3Lamsv/3/ i cant find a problem here , may be you can share?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the problem - perhaps I am misunderstanding exactly what it is. The animation from 0 to 1 opacity is in a very quick time but is there as far as I can see. And there should be no way opacity can upset scrollability. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and create a runnable snippet which definitely shows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, problem was that i used opacity instead of filter:opacity, now i get opacity effect without scrolling problems